# Comparing if Item in List(A) exists as Sub-Item in List(B)

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

I have 2 lists, each as a collection of Strings and want to check if an Item of `list(A)` exists in another item of `list(B)`.
So in `list(A)` there are the criteria-words and phrases that should be found in `list(B)`.
I filled `List(A)` with this `(e.g. "innovation", "innovative", "new ways to go")` and `lemmatized` it `(['innovation'], ['innovative'], ['new', 'way', 'go']`.

In `list(B)` there are `tokenized` and `lemmatized` sentences of a text `('time', new', 'way', 'go']`.

In that schema I try to analyze text whether and how often given words and phrases appear in it.

To match the patterns I read that its needed to convert each list-element itself to a string to check if it's a substring of the strings in `list(b)`.

```
    list_a = [['innovation'], ['innovative'], ['new', 'way', 'go'], ['set', 'trend']]
    list_b = [['time', 'innovation'], ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way'],  ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']]

    for x in range(len(list_a)):
        for j in range(len(list_b)):
            a = " ".join(list_a[x])
            if any(a in s for s in list_b[j]):
                print("word of list a: ", a, " appears in list b: ", list_b[j])    `
```

actual output is:

```
word of list a:  innovation  appears in list b:  ['time', 'innovation']
word of list a:  innovative  appears in list b:  ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']
```

my aimed output would be:

```
word of list a:  innovation  appears in list b:  ['time', 'innovation']
word of list a:  innovative  appears in list b:  ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']
word of list a: new way go appears in list b: ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way']
```

Converting the items of `list(b)` to strings like i tried with `list(a)` did not help me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you only interested in printing when any word from A matches any word from B, oronly if all words from A are contained in B. So for example if you had an element in B as `['go','time']` should this be printed as a match for `['new', 'way', 'go']` or should B only match if it contains all items from A

Comment: It should only match if all words of the criterium in A occur in list B. Additionally it should not lose the semantics of the phrase (the words should not be spread over the sentence without the actual meaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is: don't create a string out of your list of words. Work with `set` of words and the set methods (here: `issubset`)

- convert your list of lists of words to lists of set of words
- loop in sets of first list (a) and check if the set is *contained* in one of the sets of `list_b` (not using `any` else we cannot know *which* set contains the current set, a simple loop will do)

Like this:

```
list_a = [['innovation'], ['innovative'], ['new', 'way', 'go'], ['set', 'trend']]
list_b = [['time', 'innovation'], ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way'],  ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']]

list_a = [set(x) for x in list_a]
list_b = [set(x) for x in list_b]

for subset in list_a:
    for other_subset in list_b:
        if subset.issubset(other_subset):
            print("{} appears in list b: {}".format(subset,other_subset))
```

prints:

```
{'innovation'} appears in list b: {'time', 'innovation'}
{'innovative'} appears in list b: {'look', 'creative', 'innovative', 'people'}
{'new', 'go', 'way'} appears in list b: {'time', 'new', 'go', 'way'}
```

now if you want to preserve order, but still want to benefit from the advantages of a `set` for element testing, just create list of tuples instead for `list_b` because it's iterated several times. No need to do the same for `list_a` as it's iterated only once:

```
# list_a is now unchanged
list_b = [(set(x),x) for x in list_b]

for sublist in list_a:
    subset = set(sublist)
    for other_subset,other_sublist in list_b:
        if subset.issubset(other_subset):
            print("{} appears in list b: {}".format(sublist,other_sublist))
```

result:

```
['innovation'] appears in list b: ['time', 'innovation']
['innovative'] appears in list b: ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']
['new', 'way', 'go'] appears in list b: ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way']
```

Algorithm is still costly: `O(n**3)` but not `O(n**4)` thanks to `O(n)` set lookup (compared to list lookup) to test if a list of words is included in the other one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still quite new into Python and did not understand the necessity to use a set for this. The set breaks up with the structure of the sentences, so would it still be possible to refer to the original sentence of `list(a)`? e.g.: `{'new', 'go', 'way'} appears in list b: {'time', 'go', 'new', 'way'}`)

Comment: yes, but that would require a dictionary with a frozenset as key and the original sentence as value. Doable. Let me fix this in a few

Comment: Would it further be implementable to set the condition that the distance between words is not too big? Just to prevent to match a sentence like "I am new here and don't know which way to go" with the criterium "go new way"?

Comment: that looks like a totally different question (and more complex). I have edited in the meanwhile to demonstrate an efficient solution which preserves word order in sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to match when all words in one of the lists in a are contained in one of the lists in B then you could use.

```
list_a = [['innovation'], ['innovative'], ['new', 'way', 'go'], ['set', 'trend']]
list_b = [['time', 'innovation'], ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way'], ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people'], ['way', 'go', 'time']]

for a_element in list_a:
    for b_element in list_b:
        for a_element_item in a_element:
            if a_element_item not in b_element:
                break
        else:
            print(a_element, "is in ", b_element)
```

output

```
['innovation'] is in  ['time', 'innovation']
['innovative'] is in  ['look', 'innovative', 'creative', 'people']
['new', 'way', 'go'] is in  ['time', 'go', 'new', 'way']
```